# Is there a way in aws lambda where I can trigger a hook before handler is invoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a rest api using serverless framework with the following endpoints,

GET /clients/{id}

POST /clients/{id}/payments{type}

both clients and payments having it's own handlers. I want to know if there is a way by which I can get the client details injected to the payment handler by some sort of hooks rather than calling the code to fetch the client with in the payment handler. This way handlers of all sub-resources of clients will not need to fetch the client details with in the handler. It would be interesting, if I can utilize the plugins of serverless framework to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can see to achieve this is by using the [custom authorizer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/), it's not for that was designed but you can have it to send to your request context with your client and the policies to allow your api. Then you can cache the authorizer response which means it will cache your client.

example of  authorizer response

```
{
  "principalId": "192389128578129703612946127317023",
  "policyDocument": {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:1234567890:apiId/stage/*/*"
        }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "client": <your client object>
  }
}
```

Then you can get your client

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 const client = event.requestContext.authorizer.client;
....
 callback(null, paymentResponse);
};
```

This only makes sense if you are going to cache the authorizer response, otherwise you would be better to have your payments handler to fetch the client instead.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the quick response. I did initially think of using authorizer. However, as you said it is not designed for this, and so I think wouldn't be ideal in this scenario. I thought there would be something in serverless framework that would help achieve this.